# global excel worksheet formula

Tags: excel

In Excel, is there a way to create a global worksheet formula that encompasses the whole worksheet for the function `=If(denominator=0,"",numerator/denominator)`?

Essentially, I have a large worksheet that is returning `#DIV/0!` in many of my cells. I want the result to return zero or blank.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you **cannot intercept standard calculation** in Excel formula (if someone does, please tell us :)).

You can **use another Worksheet** to display the results by checking if your cell has an error with formulas like [`ISERROR()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/iserror.php)

Comment: Thank you JMax. I will have to modify all of the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007 onward, there is also the function IFERROR.
You could try

```
=IFERROR(numerator/denominator,"")
```